# Can't change items in ForeignCollection with ORMLite?

Tags: java, android, database, orm, ormlite

I have a class like this:

A 1->* B 1->* C

So A has a list of B's and every B has a list of C's. Now all the lists are eager loaded, but when I retrieve A, and I do the following:

In the database C has a value of 1.

Class C:

```
public class C {

    private int value;

    public void setValue(int i){
       this.value = i;
    }
}
```

Logic in some other class:

```
for (B b : a.getBList()) {
    for(C c : b.getCList()) {
        c.setValue(2);
    }
}
```

After the logic, the value in C is still 1.
Why is this? I figured that if I set everything to eager, I would just get the complete object tree from the database. I also have set maxEagerLevel=10 (I'm not going that deep, but just to be sure).

I have read the documentation and looked at the source code, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you called `cdao.update(c);` after `c.setValue(2);`?

Comment: I wasn't trying to update the object yet. I just got the object from the database and tried to call a setter method on it,  but for some reason I couldn't change any value on the object. I got around it by creating a deep copy of the object and using that